# Is there a way to simplify the creation of all possible (length x height) grids?

Tags: python, tree

Here's my code for a 4x4 grid to better explain my problem:

```
    #The "Duct-Tape" solution
    for box0 in range(0,2):
        for box1 in range(0,2):
            for box2 in range(0,2):
                for box3 in range(0,2):
                    for box4 in range(0,2):
                        for box5 in range(0,2):
                            for box6 in range(0,2):
                                for box7 in range(0,2): #0 = OutBag, 1 = InBag
                                    for box8 in range(0,2):
                                        for box9 in range(0,2):
                                            for box10 in range(0,2):
                                                for box11 in range(0,2):
                                                    for box12 in range(0,2):
                                                        for box13 in range(0,2):
                                                            for box14 in range(0,2):
                                                                for box15 in range(0,2):
                                                                    totalGrids.append([[box0,box1,box2,box3],
                                                                                         [box4,box5,box6,box7],
                                                                                         [box8,box9,box10,box11],
                                                                                         [box12,box13,box14,box15]])
```

What's a way to make something like this for a length x height size grid?

Comment: You want all possible width x height grids with each cell being either 1 or 0?

Comment: @Harith Yes that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another way to do it with fewer `for` loops by using binary arithmetic:

```
totalGrids = []
for i in range(0, 1 << 16):
    totalGrids.append(
        [
            [(i >> j) & 1 for j in range(0, 4)], 
            [(i >> j) & 1 for j in range(4, 8)], 
            [(i >> j) & 1 for j in range(8, 12)], 
            [(i >> j) & 1 for j in range(12, 16)]
        ])
print(totalGrids[0])
print(totalGrids[1])
print(totalGrids[2])
print()
print(totalGrids[-3])
print(totalGrids[-2])
print(totalGrids[-1])
```

Output (first 3 and last 3 elements):

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]

[[1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
[[0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

To generalize this from 4 x 4 to `height` x `width`, something like this should work:

```
height = 3
width = 5
totalGrids = []
for i in range(0, 1 << (height * width)):
    totalGrids.append(
        [[(i >> j) & 1 for j in range(k * width, (k + 1) * width)] for k in range(0, height)]
    )
```

Here is an explanation of the above.

- The matrix, which has `height` x `width` elements, is to be filled with every possible combination of 0s and 1s across these elements. As an example, if `height` = 2 and `width` = 4, then there are 8 elements in total, and one ordering of the required combinations of 0s and 1s is:

```
0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 (this is 0 in binary)
0 0 0 0   0 0 0 1 (this is 1 in binary)
0 0 0 0   0 0 1 0 (this is 2 in binary)
0 0 0 0   0 0 1 1 (this is 3 in binary)
...
0 0 0 0   1 1 1 1 (this is 15 in binary)
0 0 0 1   0 0 0 0 (this is 16 in binary)
0 0 0 1   0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1   0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1   0 0 1 1 (EXAMPLE VALUE USED BELOW)
...
0 0 1 0   0 0 0 0 (this is 32 in binary)
...
0 0 1 1   0 0 0 0 (this is 48 in binary)
...
1 1 1 1   1 1 1 1 (this is 255 = 2**8 - 1 in binary)
```

These are just the binary values from 0 to `2**8 - 1` which can be expressed as Python integers in `range(0, 2**8)`. They are exactly what is needed, and now the only question is how to populate a Python `list` of `lists` of size `height` x `width`.

The answer is to use binary arithmetic. Let's look at `0 0 0 1   0 0 1 1` as an example. We can specify this in Python as an integer, namely `i = 19`.

For the `1st` slot of 8, we want to use the rightmost binary bit in our example, which is `1`. We can extract this using Python's bitwise `&` operation by taking `value = i & 1`. Applying `& 1` to any integer effectively masks off all but the binary ones-place digit.

For the `2nd` slot, we need to add an additional step:

- First we slide the bits to the right by 1 position (allowing the rightmost bit to fall off the edge, which is fine since we have already processed it and won't need it again) using Python's `right shift` operation `>>` as follows: `value = i >> 1`. In binary, this yields `0 0 0 0   1 0 0 1`, which is the integer 9. The right-shift operator has moved the bit that was in the binary twos-place rightward into the binary ones-place.
- Next, we can use the same technique as we did for the `1st` slot to mask off all but the ones-place bit: `value = i & 1`.
- Rather than do the above as two separate statements, we can simply write: `value = (i >> 1) & 1`.

In general, for the `j'th` slot, we can extract the `j'th` bit from our example integer by writing: `value = (i >> j) & 1`.

Now let's look at the key logic within the loop:

```
[[(i >> j) & 1 for j in range(k * width, (k + 1) * width)] for k in range(0, height)]
```

This uses a nested `list comprehension` to loop first over `k` in `range(0, height)` and then over `j` in `range(k * width, (k + 1) * width)`, and to put the result of the above bitwise expression `(i >> j) & 1` into each successive element in our matrix (or `list` of `lists`).

Finally, let's look again at the very outer loop in the code:

```
for i in range(0, 1 << (height * width)):
```

This uses Python's bitwise `left shift` operation `<<`, which does the opposite of what `right shift` (`>>`) does, namely to shift the bits of `1` to the left by `(height * width)` binary positions. Because each shift to the left causes a number to double in value, our `left shift` expression gives the same result as `2 ** (height * width)`, which is exactly the number of 0/1 combinations that your question is seeking.

So, by iterating from 0 to 2 ** (height * width), then extracting and collating the bits of each value into the corresponding matrix elements for that iteration's matrix, and appending that matrix to the `totalGrids` variable, we ultimately construct a list of matrices with the required properties.

Comment: Thank you! Although I don't understand exactly what your code is doing, it does work.

Comment: @Ben Bradlow Please take a look at the updated answer which provides a detailed explanaion.